# Eclipse "CLEAR KEY" (numpad 5 with NumLock off)

Tags: linux, eclipse

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and Eclipse 3.5.2.  Is there a way to get Eclipse to recognize the numpad-5 key with numlock off (called VK_CLEAR in Windows, and either KP_CLEAR or KP_BEGIN in Linux)?  I use the key in both NetBeans and CodeLite to re-center the current line in the text editor window.

Comment: what is super user in this context?

Comment: @daniel - Questions about configuring development tools are entirely on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm beginning to believe this issue has more to do with Ubuntu Linux 10.04 than Eclipse, because other apps will not recognize the numpad 5 key with numlock off, including CodeLite, VMware and virtualized Windows instances running in VMware.